# Java Object array is displaying null

Tags: java, arrays, object

I need to open a text file using an object array, and display it to the console output.
The text file is a table with 7 columns.
I have created an object array. Currently it is displaying:

"F:\stock.txt14 lines
[[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null] ..... etc." which should be the information from each column.

I've been stuck on this for a while since i am unsure of how to do. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Stock {

    public Object [][] makeArray() throws IOException {

        int L = 0;
        int currentLine = 0;
        int next = 1;

        File stockFile = new File ("F:\\stock.txt");
        Scanner s = null;
        Scanner input = null;
        System.out.print(stockFile);

        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("F:\\stock.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.err.println("Error opening stock file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            s = new Scanner (stockFile);        //scan file
            while (s.hasNext()){
                L = L+1;                            //read line
                s.nextLine();                       //read next line
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (s != null){                     //if no more line
                s.close();                      //close
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + L + " lines");

        Object[] partID = new Object[L];
        Object[] manufacturer = new Object[L];
        Object[] partNo = new Object[L];
        Object[] description = new Object[L];
        Object[] stockLevel = new Object[L];
        Object[] lowStock = new Object[L];
        Object[] location = new Object[L];
        Object[][] stockArray = new Object [][] {partID, manufacturer, partNo, description, stockLevel, lowStock, location};

        Scanner fillArray = null;

        return stockArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never save any information to the arrays, so the elements are `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop need to parse the line being read to extract the values you need and store them somewhere.

```
while (s.hasNext()){
    // parse out data and store somewhere
}
```

Currently you are reading the line, but doing nothing with the data read from the file